# Don't show image, only alternate text with CSS

Tags: css, image, alt

Is it possible to have CSS render an image invisible so only the alternate text shows?

I have an image that doesn't look good on mobile devices so I rather show the alternate text instead and style it accordingly.

Comment: No big deal: <img src="image.gif" alt="some text">

Comment: You could use something like [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15254383).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive CSS: Can I force rendering of alt text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254207/responsive-css-can-i-force-rendering-of-alt-text)

Comment: there's no way to clear source of an image with css. But you can use some helper div and show it on mobile. and hide your image on mobile

Comment: @HiDeo I considered using that at the beginning but that would imply to have the same text twice. Everything would be easier if IMG could accept pseudo elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

html

```
<div class="example">
<image src="img.jpg" alt="alternative text">
</div>
```

css

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { /* change to any number you want */
    div.example img{
        display:none;
    }
    div.example:after{
        content:"alternative text";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you're able to tell if visitor is on mobile why not just hide the image and show regular text?  If you're using responsive CSS that knows mobile size or not you can just do it via CSS.

```
<style>
.isMobileView #BlurryImg{display:none;}
.isMobileView #MobileTxt(display:block;}
</style>
<img id="BlurryImg" src="image.gif" alt="some text"/>
<span id="MobileTxt" style="display:none;">some text</span>
```

Comment: and isMobileView class comnig from?

Comment: Because that will force me to have the same text twice.